# How to display specific item in vector<char>? (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

As part of a Tic-Tac-Toe game I'm trying to create a char vector that is filled with the numbers 1-9. Why doesn't the following code work? This is just a simplified version of the full code, all of it probably would have been a bit unwieldy. Should this do what I want it to? Why wouldn't it `cout` '0'? It seems to be empty when I try to display what's inside. Did I populate the vector incorrectly?

Yes, I know `using namespace std;` is bad.

```
include <iostream>
include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    const int NUM_SQUARES = 9;
    vector<char> board(NUM_SQUARES);
    cout << board[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code shouldn't even compile

Comment: @Ap31 Please point out why. Is it the lack of `void` that's worrying you?

Comment: @byxor it should now, fixed by dasblinkenlight :)

Comment: @byxor the `include` do not have `#` and `board` is not defined.

Comment: Ouch. I must be tired, or just looking too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Your code prints the content of the initial element of the vector, so it's only a matter of what character you put into that element.

Your code puts character zero `'\0'` there, which is non-printable. If you would like to print a character digit, put it in the vector:

```
vector<char> box(NUM_SQUARES, 'X');
cout << board[0] << endl; // prints X
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/73jSDf)

Answer (score 0):

Because you store it as char, just like

```
char c=0;
std::cout << c;
```

would not print anything.

If you want to show `0`, you need to cast it to `int` i.e. `std::cout << (int)board[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a `vector` with an initial count of 9, but no initial values, so the characters are all initialized to `'\0'` (0x00), not `'0'` (0x30).  You need to populate the `vector` before you display it, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    const int NUM_SQUARES = 9;
    std::vector<char> board(NUM_SQUARES);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SQUARES; ++i)
        board[i] = '0' + i;
    std::cout << board[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or, in C++11 and later:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main () {
    const int NUM_SQUARES = 9;
    std::vector<char> board(NUM_SQUARES);
    std::iota(board.begin(), board.end(), '0');
    std::cout << board[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Vectors aren't arrays. You don't need to reserve memory space beforehand. Just declare an empty vector then use a for loop to populate said vector.

Or, better yet, since you need exactly 9 elements and that's never going to change, just declare a character array.

Comment: how is `vector::vector(int)` "not overloaded"? it's probably the most abused vector constructor